# Get production versions of packages on "composer install"

Tags: composer-php

Since composer was created, it made our life a lot easier. However, running `composer install` often ends up with so many files that can be useful for development, but just bloat the production server. Shared hosting often has limited inodes, or you must upload the "vendor" folder yourself since composer isn't on the server.

When the vendor folder has 6,000 files+ this is an issue, especially if you have multiple projects with 6,000 files each. And so many of these files are "README.MD" or "TODO". Production servers don't need the dev's "TODO" file.

I tried searching on Google but I can't find any clues, so anyone knows if there is a composer command that will install a production version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a [feature request](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5367) for that, but it was rejected (several times). Right now the best what you can get from Composer is:

```
composer install --no-dev --prefer-dist
```

It will skip installation dev packages and prefer dist archives, which usually does not contain tests and other files not necessary to run package on production.

If this is still not enough, you may try to use [`octolab/cleaner`](https://github.com/octolab/Cleaner) plugin.

Comment: Thanks friend, this is the best option so far so I'll accept as an answer and if it ever gets implemented in Composer, you can edit your answer ;)

Comment: Doesn't composer uses "--prefer-dist" by default if you don't specify it?

Comment: @NaturalBornCamper The default is `auto` which will use dist for releases (tags) and source for branches.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand XD I didn't see anything about "auto" and I thought from the doc, "dist" was default: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install-i

Comment: *For **stable versions** Composer will use the dist by default*. If you have unstable branch (like `dev-master`) in your `composer.json`, by default Composer will checkout it from git repo. If you use `--prefer-dist`, Composer will download zip archive with library.

Answer (score 0):

`composer install --no-dev`

The official link:

https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install

If you want to exclude something very specific, you want `archive`.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#archive

```
"archive": {
     "exclude": ["*.md", "vendor/**/tests", "/*.test"]
}
```

Comment: I know this option but thanks for your answer :) What I mean is to not include all the unneeded readme files and such that will be included anyways in --no-dev

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a good idea, however it downloads as many files (6,442 Files) with exclude in composer.json. So there's no way to exclude licenses and other files that don't have an extension right? BEcause composer has no way of knowing which file is only for dev

Comment: Not entirely.  I think most of the files are just called LICENSE.  Since it accepts glob patterns, "vendor/**/license" should work.