# Laravel blank projects.. so many files! Can it be reduced somehow?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

Last time I used Laravel was a long time ago and I decided to get back to it.

Now coming from CodeIgniter, which was a powerful framework in its own time, I was happy to upload projects to websites as the "system" folder containing the framework files contained only 121 files.

The problem with composer-based solutions however is that a tiny project can become huge, much bigger than a very large scale CodeIgniter project back in the days. All the dependencies have test folders, documentation, and tons of modules when sometimes only one method is used.

I gasped when creating an empty Laravel project using the instructions from the official documentation and seeing the "vendor" folder containing over 8,000 files!! (Not counting the folders) And it's doing nothing yet.. That is when using the `--prefer-dist` flag by the way. And I know about the `--no-dev` argument, which still has 5,000+ files. My point was that there is no way all these files are used, especially when using the distribution channel.

So my question is if there is a way to have a more selective empty Laravel project, as servers often have limited Inodes and 8,000 files + folders for every project makes you reach the limit really quickly (and upload takes forever if you can't install composer on your server).

Comment: Do you have ssh acces and Git installed to your hosting?

Comment: I suppose you could have choosing lumen which is skinner version of laravel

Comment: @NaingLinAung Lumen 5.7 has ~6100 files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get production versions of packages on "composer install"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50179162/get-production-versions-of-packages-on-composer-install)

Comment: Yes I have ssh and git, but I would prefer not to use composer directly on a prod server, upload files or package instead. I thought Lumen was mostly used for APIs? Thanks @rob006, I added some details, your link is related but not exactly what I mean; feels like even with --no-dev and --prefer-dist, the amount of files is ridiculous

Comment: @NaturalBornCamper I encourage you to read the whole answer, especially the last sentence.

Comment: That's right, I had opened the cleaner link and lost it in all my documentation and SO answers tabs. It looks quite complicated from the docs, especially since I'm relatively new to composer and still don't see how to launch the clean command, but I'll have a deeper look. Hopefully it's still accurate as it's alpha

Answer (score 2):

Composer can remove extraneous files.

In your project's `composer.json`, specify the files you don't want with either the [`archive`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#archive) and/or [`exclude-files-from-classmaps`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#exclude-files-from-classmaps) configuration values, then use composer's [`archive`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#archive) command to create a zip. Upload the zip and expand on the server, or expand locally and transfer the now smaller package.

```
$ cat composer.json
...
{
    "archive": {
        "exclude": ["!vendor", "/test/*", "/*.jpg" ]
    }
}
$ php composer.phar archive --format=zip --file=<filename-without-extension>
```

Those files matched by `archive` will not be present, at all, in your zip. Those files matched by `exclude-files-from-classmaps` will be present in the filesystem, but invisible to the autoloader.

Comment: Your solution seemed like the best possible choice to limit Inodes since I can't have a stripped version of Laravel (and I didn't know the archive command), but I still have all the "test" folders in the "vendor" folder. For once I had to add "!vendor/" in "exclude", thenany kind of "/test/", "vendor/test", '**/test*", (etc etc) didn't change anything, still have all of them.

Comment: Sounds like a separate question, @NaturalBornCamper.

Answer (score 1):

I had a Same Situation Before few Days so i have created the console command to delete the unused files in the **vendor**  Directory

Step :1

```
php artisan make:command CleanVendorFolderCommand
```

Step: 2

Copy the current code and paste int in the Command Class

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use RecursiveIteratorIterator;
use RecursiveDirectoryIterator;
use FilesystemIterator;

class CleanVendorFolderCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'clean:vendor {--o : Verbose Output} {--dry : Runs in dry mode without deleting files.}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Cleans up useless files from  vendor folder.';

    protected $patterns = 
            [
                'test',
                'tests',
                '.github',
                'README',
                'CHANGELOG',
                'FAQ',
                'CONTRIBUTING',
                'HISTORY',
                'UPGRADING',
                'UPGRADE',
                'demo',
                'example',
                'examples',
                '.doc',
                'readme',
                'changelog',
                'composer',
                '.git',
                '.gitignore',
                '*.md',
                '.*.yml',
                '*.yml',
                '*.txt',
                '*.dist',
                'LICENSE',
                'AUTHORS',
                '.eslintrc',
                'ChangeLog',
                '.gitignore',
                '.editorconfig',
                '*.xml',                
                '.npmignore',
                '.jshintrc',
                'Makefile',
                '.keep',

            ];
    /**
     * List of File and Folders Patters Going To Be Excluded
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected $excluded = 
            [
                /**List of  Folders*/
                'src',
                /**List of  Files*/
                '*.php',
                '*.stub',
                '*.js',
                '*.json',
            ];
    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle() 
    {
        $patterns = array_diff($this->patterns, $this->excluded);

        $directories = $this->expandTree(base_path('vendor'));

        $isDry = $this->option('dry');

        foreach ($directories as $directory) 
        {
            foreach ($patterns as $pattern) 
            {
                $casePattern = preg_replace_callback('/([a-z])/i', [$this, 'prepareWord'], $pattern);
                $files = glob($directory . '/' . $casePattern, GLOB_BRACE);
                if (!$files) 
                {
                    continue;
                }

                $files = array_diff($files, $this->excluded);
                foreach ($this->excluded as $excluded) 
                {
                    $key = $this->arrayFind($excluded, $files);

                    if ($key !== false) 
                    {
                        $this->warn('SKIPPED: ' . $files[$key]);
                        unset($files[$key]);
                    }
                }
                foreach ($files as $file) 
                {
                    if (is_dir($file)) 
                    {
                        $this->warn('DELETING DIR: ' . $file);
                        if (!$isDry) 
                        {
                            $this->delTree($file);
                        }
                    } else 
                    {
                        $this->warn('DELETING FILE: ' . $file);
                        if (!$isDry) 
                        {
                            @unlink($file);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $this->warn('Folder Cleanup Done!');
    }
    /**
     * Recursively traverses the directory tree
     *
     * @param  string $dir
     * @return array
     */
    protected function expandTree($dir) 
    {
        $directories = [];
        $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), ['.', '..']);
        foreach ($files as $file) 
        {
            $directory = $dir . '/' . $file;
            if (is_dir($directory)) 
            {
                $directories[] = $directory;
                $directories = array_merge($directories, $this->expandTree($directory));
            }
        }
        return $directories;
    }
    /**
     * Recursively deletes the directory
     *
     * @param  string $dir
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function delTree($dir) {
        if (!file_exists($dir) || !is_dir($dir)) 
        {
            return false;
        }

        $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
        foreach ($iterator as $filename => $fileInfo) 
        {
            if ($fileInfo->isDir()) 
            {
                @rmdir($filename);
            } else {
                @unlink($filename);
            }
        }
        @rmdir($dir);
    }
    /**
     * Prepare word
     *
     * @param  string $matches
     * @return string
     */
    protected function prepareWord($matches) 
    {
        return '[' . strtolower($matches[1]) . strtoupper($matches[1]) . ']';
    }
    protected function arrayFind($needle, array $haystack) 
    {
        foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) 
        {
            if (false !== stripos($value, $needle)) 
            {
                return $key;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    protected function out($message) 
    {
        if ($this->option('o') || $this->option('dry')) 
        {
            echo $message . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

TESTED ON

`OS Name`   **Microsoft Windows 10 Pro**

`Version`   **10.0.16299 Build 16299**

`Processor` **Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-7100U CPU @ 2.40GHz, 2400 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)**

> **NOW THE TESTING PART**

**Before Size of vendor Folder**

`Size` **57.0 MB (5,98,29,604 bytes)**

`Size on disk`  **75.2 MB (7,88,80,768 bytes)**

`Contains`  **12,455 Files, 2,294 Folders**

Now Run the Command

```
php artisan clean:vendor
```

**Size of vendor Folder after Running the command**

`Size` **47.0 MB (4,93,51,781 bytes)**

`Size on disk`  **59.7 MB (6,26,76,992 bytes)**

`Contains`  **8,431 Files, 1,570 Folders**

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it reduced quite a lot! It's a bit complicated so I might not use it right away, but might very well get back to it. You haven't run into any problems so far using it? Missing classes, files, etc?

Comment: kindly see `$excluded` property for the excluded file extension